# Unable to apply aspects to String class

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, aspect

I was experimenting with `AspectJ`. I tried to apply aspect on String class. I created Spring configuration file as:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd ">

    <!-- Enable @AspectJ annotation support -->
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <!-- Employee manager -->
    <bean id="employeeManager" class="com.test.advice.EmployeeManager" />

    <!-- Logging Aspect -->
    <bean id="loggingAspect" class="com.test.advice.LoggingAspect" />

    <bean id="bean1" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="abx" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Then an Aspect class like,

```
package com.test.advice;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect
{

    @Around("execution(* java.lang.String.*(..))")
    public void logAroundGetEmployee(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable
    {
        System.out.println("works");
    }
}
```

After that created a class with a main method like:

```
package com.test.advice;

package com.test.advice;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class AspectJAutoProxyTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Customer.xml");

        String pqr = (String) context.getBean("bean1");

        pqr.trim();

    }
}
```

On running it should output "works" to console. But it fails saying,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at com.test.advice.AspectJAutoProxyTest.main(AspectJAutoProxyTest.java:13)
```

What is the issue? Can't we apply proxy to java.lang objects? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a proxy object as a replacement for the real object, the proxy object must be of a subclass of the real object. `String` being `final`, the JVM does not permit creating such a subclass.

(Note that spring has two proxy modes; one creates an actual subclass and the other just implements all public interfaces. You're probably using the latter, but if you changed to the former, you'd see an exception at proxy creation time)

Comment: That's only a small part of the problem and not the real answer. Even if String was not final, it (a) is not a Spring bean and thus not noticed by Spring AOP, (b) even if you switch to AspectJ in order to remove this limitation, you cannot weave into JDK classes via load-time weaving because those classes have been loaded before the weaving agent kicks in. But using AspectJ you can at least use `call(* java.lang.String.*(..))` and thus intercept the call sites within your own or load-time woven 3rd party classes.

Comment: Actually, OP does declare a String as a Spring bean: `<bean id="bean1" class="java.lang.String">`.

Comment: True. It does not really matter though, because `execution(* java.lang.String.*(..))` is off limits for Spring AOP. Yeah, theoretically it could be dynamically proxied if it was not final. But that would not help.

Comment: What evidence do you have for that pointcut being "off limits"? The exception shown in the question demonstrates that Spring AOP has decided to proxy the bean - and Spring AOP only proxies beans that match a pointcut. (Yes, I know that load-time weaving can not decorate JDK classes, but proxy creation works just fine for spring beans of JDK classes as long as they are not final)

Comment: Thanks for challenging my argument and making me think about it again. You are right with regard to dynamic proxies (i.e. Spring AOP). In theory, if String was not final, it could be proxied as a subclass of String and casted back to its parent. If you run the above program you even have a working proxy, it also has all the String methods from implemented interfaces `Serializable`, `CharSequence`, `Comparable<String>`. I.e. the aspect kicks in if you do `((CharSequence) appContext.getBean("bean1")).subSequence(1, 3) `. So "off-limits" really only applies to AspectJ in this case.